# Alibaba cloud Message queue (MNS) Signature issue

Tags: message-queuing, alibaba-cloud

I am trying to send messages to my Alibaba cloud MNS endpoint using postman. For that I am using [this tool](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/34490.htm) provided by alibaba to generate the signature. However, no matter what I try, I am getting

`<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>`

`<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>`

Have any of were able to send a successful request using postman to the Alibaba MNS?

Answer (score 0):

i think you problem maybe Signature authentication fails when using the HTTPEndpoint interface of message service

The reason maybe When the HTTP server framework is used, it may convert the format of parameters in the HttpHeader. For example, in the HTTP Endpoint interface x-mns-message-id parameter. After format conversion in some frameworks, the parameter X-Mns-Message-Id。

suggest you Before signature authentication, use the function or method to convert the parameters in the HttpHeader into lowercase letters.